Структуры с динамическими массивами в Си
Какая есть структура данных, которая позволяет хранить множество элементов разного размера и которую можно реализовать в C? Как мне такое сделать? Вроде как есть связный список, но поискав в интернете, я нашёл только реализации, в которых в элементах хранится только обычный int, а не что-то посложнее
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t product_id;
    uint32_t user_id;
    uint8_t  rating;
    char*    advantages;
    char*    disadvantages;
    char*    feedback;
} Comment;


Показанная в вашем коде структура имеет вполне статический размер, так что непонятно в чём проблема у вас

Если считать только указатели на динамические массивы, то да, статический размер. А если я решу выделить память на динамический массив через malloc внутри одного элемента из множества элементов? Они будут хранится в памяти Которую я выделю с помощью Comment comment = (Comment*)malloc(sizeof(Comment))? Или вообще выделится новая память?

Размер указателя от этого не поменяется никак, выделенная память физически находится не в структуре

malloc(sizeof(Comment)) выделит только память для одной структуры Comment и ничего более. Причем память останется неинициализированной и выделять дополнительную память и присваивать значения полям advantages и прочим вам придется потом дополнительно.

Есть две разновидности, так сказать, два подхода...
struct Test
{
    char *d;
    char s[1];
};

После этого вы можете динамически выделять память типа
struct Test ts;
ts.d = malloc(123);

(не забудьте потом ее удалить). А для s можете выделять иначе:
struct Test * td = malloc(123);

После этого фактически td->s получается большим массивом, в который вы можете безопасно писать достаточно длинные строки.
strcpy(ts.d, "Hello");
strcpy(td->s,"Dolly");


"второй подход" видимо подразумевал использование Flexible array member, однако 1) вместо него тут просто массив из одного элемента, выход за пределы которого будет караться, как обычно 2) это сомнительная "фича", а с учетом того, что ОП уже три поля хотел в структуре - вообще бесполезная 3) блок памяти можно выделить сразу большой и без этого

@user7860670 Этот способ регулярно используется в Windows API. Претензии к Microsoft. И уж точно о трех полях - претензии не в тему. Я рассказал о подходах, а не о том, как решить конкретную (не поставленную!) задачу.
